# Problemas al bloquear una carpeta con .htpaswd y .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, .htpasswd

Quiero bloquear una carpeta y todo lo que esté en ella con .htaccess y .htpaswd. Mi directorio es algo similar a esto:

```
admin/
css/
js/
index.html
```

Lo que quiero es bloquear la carpeta admin/ y todo lo que esta contenga, cómo puedo hacerlo con .htpaswd? He intentado con este codigo en mi .htacess pero no funciona (no funciona en el sentido que no me pide usuario ni contraseña para ingresar):

```
# Activar el uso del archivo .htaccess
RewriteEngine on

# Redireccionar a https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

<Directory "/admin">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Acceso restringido"
    AuthUserFile .htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Mi .htpaswd:

```
CaroRomera:$2y$1ads.RYV8cTYZSCWdkH4bT6W
```

Y en mi .htpaswd tengo el usuario y la contraseña. Espero que alguien me

Answer (score 0):

A mí me funciona del siguiente modo:

1. Creo un archivo `.htaccess` en el directorio que quiero proteger, en tu caso, dentro de `admin`, con este contenido:

   ```
   authType Basic
   AuthName "privado"
   AuthUserFile /home/.htpasswds/.htpasswd
   require valid-user
   ErrorDocument 401 "Authorisation Required"
   ```

   Es IMPORTANTE que la ruta que pones en `AuthUserFile` **sea correcta**, aquí he asumido que en `home` tienes una carpeta **oculta** llamada `.htpasswds` y dentro de ella un archivo, **también oculto** llamado `.htpasswd` (con dos `ss` antes de la `d`). Considera también garantizar un nivel de seguridad de acceso adecuado para esos archivos. Considera también NO colocar esos archivos dentro de tu directorio `public`, o `public_html` o `www` o el que sea, según tu contexto, ni en ningún otro directorio público.
2. Dentro de tu archivo en `laRutaCorrecta/.htpasswd` tu contraseña, como ya la tienes, y que supongo ha sido **encriptada** previamente:

   ```
   CaroRomera:$2y$1ads.RYV8cTYZSCWdkH4bT6W
   ```

Así debería funcionar. En el pasado, recuerdo que no me funcionó con `<Directory>...</Directory>` por el hecho de estar en un hosting compartido en el cual no me daban permiso para usar esa directiva, no sé si sea tu caso.